# Insert Next Max Value Using SELECT INTO Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert the next max value of number column into TABLE_A each time when I insert bulk data into Table_A from TABLE_B. However, the numbers do not increase by 1 each time and stay the same all the time. Can we achieve it without using identity property? Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_A
( 
    NUMBER,
    VALUE
)
SELECT DISTINCT 
    (SELECT MAX(NUMBER)+1 FROM TABLE_A WHERE NAME='TEXT'),
    VALUE
FROM TABLE_B
```

Comment: If the values stored in number column has not changed or increased in value since the last time you executed the query, then your numbers won’t increase. What exactly is your end goal that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You should really use an `INT IDENTITY` column and let the database handle the auto-incrementing behavior. The `SELECT MAX(..)+1` approach is **flawed** and will produce **duplicates** in a busy system with concurrent users.... **don't do it!**

Comment: My goal is the number column increases by 1 when I insert each record into the table using the select into statement

Comment: I don't see a select into statement... but an IDENTITY PROPERTY as @marc_s mentioned is the way to go.

Comment: Can we achieve it without making it as identity column? Thanks

Comment: well you aren't inserting in to TABLE_B anywhere... if you inserted 5 records into A should 5 be in B or just the last / max one?

Comment: Not sure why you are anti identity column. If you have sql server 2012 or later then you can use a sequence. See https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-server-sequence-basics/

Comment: "Can we achieve it without making it as identity column?" You can use a [sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql).

Comment: As others have already stated: this is a **bad** idea. Use a sequence or an identity column, but not this broken pattern.

Answer (score 0):

As Marc mentioned, you should do it with the `IDENTITY PROPERTY`. Here is how:

```
DECLARE @TABLE_A TABLE(NUMBER INT IDENTITY(1,1), [VALUE] VARCHAR(16))

--notice we don't insert anything for NUMBER. This happens automatically 
INSERT INTO @TABLE_A
VALUES
('VAL 1'),
('VAL 2'),
('VAL 3'),
('VAL 4')

SELECT * FROM @TABLE_A
```

Comment: We can not create identity property on number column in TABLE_A because it only increases by one when name is certain value. In other situation, the number column is working in different way.

Comment: @Ice That would suggest to me that what you really need is two different columns. Or possibly two different tables. Trying to cram different behaviour into a single column often makes life hard.

Comment: @Ice then you need to look into [TRIGGERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use IDENTITY in the NUMBER field.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_A (
NUMBER INT PRIMARY IDENTITY (1,1),
[VALUE] VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
[NAME] VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE TABLE_B (
[VALUE] VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL
);

INSERT INTO TABLE_B ([VALUE])
VALUES ('Text1'), ('Text2'), ('Text3');


INSERT INTO TABLE_A ([VALUE])
SELECT DISTINCT
[VALENTIA]
FROM TABLE_B

SELECT
NUMBER
[VALENTIA]
FROM TABLE_A;
```

To do without the IDENTITY you have to use a LOOP, but I think it is not worth for your need ...

Result:

```
VALUE NUMBER
1 Text1
2 Text2
3 Text3
```